# How to cross-fade the image of UIImageView with blur applied

Tags: ios, uiimageview, caanimation, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I'm trying to cross-fade to a new image. This is a UIImageView that has a UIVisualEffectView added to it:

```
self.bgBlurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
self.visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:self.bgBlurEffect];

self.visualEffectView.frame = self.bgImageView.bounds;
[self.bgImageView addSubview:self.visualEffectView];
```

Here is how I'm trying to fade to the new image:

```
UIImage *toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];

CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
crossFade.duration = 2.5;
crossFade.delegate = self;
crossFade.fromValue = (id)self.bgImageView.image.CGImage;
crossFade.toValue = (id)toImage.CGImage;
[self.bgImageView.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"animateContents"];
self.bgImageView.image = toImage;
```

This actually works in the simulator, but on the device (iPhone 6), the image just goes completely gray for 2.5 seconds, then the new image appears instantly. Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: This doesn't work either:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.bgImageView
                  duration:2.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    self.bgImageView.image = toImage;
                } completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach will work for the fade animation:

```
self.bgImageView.image = toImage;

CATransition *fadeTransition = [CATransition animation];
fadeTransition.duration = 2.5;
fadeTransition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
fadeTransition.type = kCATransitionFade;

[self.bgImageView.layer addAnimation:fadeTransition forKey:nil];
```

Comment: That doesn't work. `self.bgImageView.image = toImage;` sets the new image immediately. Then 2.5 seconds later it gets blurred.

Comment: @soleil try to add visualEffectView to the same view you're adding the bgImageView to and make sure it's above the bgImageView so it blurs it (you'll also need to give it the same frame so it will cover it all). I tried that and it worked for me.